# compile drivers as module or built-in problem

Tags: linux-kernel

i compiled Linux kernel with all drivers as built-in (all network drivers also compiled as built-in). all things work but ping time goes irregular (10ms , 90ms, ...). is it from built-in mode in compilation or problem is from another thing?

Comment: Please add information about which ethernet interface device you have, and which driver is handling it, both for the malfunctioning kernel and for a good modular kernel if you have one.

Comment: my test scenario is on intel driver e100.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't change a thing. Irregular timeouts usually come from either faulty drivers (but whether you have them built-in or loaded dynamically shouldn't change anything) or faulty network.

Comment: i mean that because all drivers are in kernel maybe some other driver dos some mistakes.

Comment: Whether drivers are built-in or loaded dynamically, if the error comes from another driver, you'll be affected either way. Loading driver dynamically does not isolate them from built-in drivers in any way.